# Closure in Lua getting infinite loop

Tags: lua

I am not able to understand why this Lua code run in a continuous loop. I am under impression that, it will just execute once. Can any one explain please?

```
function testCounter()
        return function ()
                print("test function called")
                return 1
        end
end

for v in testCounter() do
        print(v)
end
```

Comment: `for` loop is executing until `nil` is returned by iterator

Comment: "and the [iterator function](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html) kept on iterating"-sounds like [Homer and the Wacky Doughnut Machine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0889999/)

Answer (score 2):

As Egor Skriptunoff correctly stated, the for loop uses the function returned by testCounter() as a `next` function. As it never returns `nil`, the loop never exits.

Comment: Well, you could accept the answer. Apart from that,  the thanks should go to Egor.